# How can I generate every possible rule based password combinations?

Tags: password-recovery

I am trying to recover a password that I have lost a few years ago.

1. I know for a fact my password contained 8 characters and the first 4
   are letters (could be lowercase or uppercase meaning AbCd, ABCD,
   Abcd, or abCd)
2. The last 4 are numbers (from 0-9)

What I did to calculate how many possibilities there is, is multiply 26 x 2 = 52 (alphabet times 2 because upper and lowercase), I then used the nCr formula, 52 C 4 = 270725, knowing that the first four characters are letters. Used the same formula, 10 C 4 = 210 which is the last 4 numbers. After that I multiplied 270725 by 210 which is 56,852,250 different combinations.

My question now is what program or how can I possibly generate those passwords.

Comment: how is the password stored? pbkdf2? scrypt? ...?

Comment: Does the application/service that requires the password have rate-limiting ?

Comment: This is a computer programming site. The assumption is that *you* will write the computer program. If you don't want to write a program, then try superuser.com.

Answer (score 0):

The program you are looking for is [John the Ripper](https://github.com/openwall/john). It's a free password-cracker software that allows you to fine-tune which password it tries, and in which order (starting with more likely password, and ending with less likely ones). [Here](https://miloserdov.org/?p=5477) is a tutorial on how to setup a rule-based "attack" with JtR.

Comment: I've already looked into JtR though didn't quite understand how I can set the rules, I've looked into the config file but still didn't understand, is there maybe an article that helps explain the terms in a more bland easier way?

Comment: I've posted a link to a tutorial in my answer, but it assumes a little bit of familiarity. [Here](https://www.hackingarticles.in/beginner-guide-john-the-ripper-part-1/) is one that will teach you the basis. Besides that, since your password is quite short, you could just let john run without any particular configuration and it will likely crack it in at most a few days, depending on your hardware configuration.

Comment: @Yskimo also, unrelated but your calculations are false... n choose r is if I have a bag with n balls, numbered from 1 to n, and I just pick r balls to put in an other bag, how many configurations that could lead to. In your case, you could pick twice the same "ball" (ie. the same caracter), so a more appropriate computation would be 52⁴=7311616, same for the end, giving a total of 73 billion possibilities, which you severely underestimated, but it's still a very small for JtR.